# Numbers : sum if tick-box on next column is true

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have 3 column in a numbers sheet

> (A) Text | (B) Currency | (C) Tickbox

At the end of *(B) Currency*, I have a very basic formula SUM(B)

What I'm trying to do is to have the same SUM(B) at the footer of *(C) Tickbox* but only add to the sum the value (in B) when there is a tick (in C)

E.g :
[image: Exemple]

my understanding is the ticked box are Boolean "true" and I need to use a kind of IF statement but I'm not sure how to SUM B only if C is true

I tried the following but obviously, it's not working :
IF(C1:C13,TRUE,SUM(B2:B13))

PS I might need to do the other way (count when tick-box is not ticked, but I assume it's the same but using false instead of true)

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7977749

Comment: I think sumproduct() will work, but don’t have time to test, but I use it with several arrays and one is true/false.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I believe I found the answer

it's seems a simple than this :

SUMIF(C, FALSE, B) (C for checkbox and B for currency)

Obviously False when I want to calculate when the tick-box are not ticked and true otherwise

Comment: Did you have to convert the last _row_ to a **Footer Row** for that _formula_ to work?  I did, but it just may be because I'm using an older version of **Numbers** (5.1 (5683))